# how to control CMS based on region using codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, translation

I am working on new project. This website can view all the country.
Here I have a problem based on country I have to change the website content for example for logout(English) i have to show déconnexion(French) for France same way others also like 'About Us','Contact' etc.Like this I have nearly 1000 words have to change. How i can implement this in a good way so that it can be easy for developing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this by using `language Class`.

**Step 1 :** First create a folder `french` inside the folder `application/language` (Here you can see an `english` floder. Which can be used for `english`).

**Step 2 :** Then create a file `content_lang.php` inside `application/language/french` and `application/language/english`.

**Step 3 :** Add the language keys indie this files like,

For english(`application/language/english/content_lang.php`),

```
$lang['gallary']='Gallery';
$lang['logout']='Sign Out';
```

For french(`application/language/french/content_lang.php`),

```
$lang['gallary']='galerie';
$lang['logout']='Déconnexion';
```

**Step 4:** In your controller you can switch language like,

```
if($lg=='fr'){ // Put your own condition for switching the language
    $this->lang->load('content','french');
}else{
    $this->lang->load('content','english');
}
```

And,

```
$data['language']=array(
        'gallery'=>$this->lang->line('gallery'),
        'logout'=>$this->lang->line('logout')           
    );
```

Then pass the `$data` array to view.

**Step 5:** In your view load the language keys like,

```
<a href="#"><?php echo $language['gallary']?></a>
<a href="#"><?php echo $language['logout']?></a>
```

Like this you can load any number of languages.

Comment: it should be $lang know how this $language variable came?

Comment: $this->lang->load('content','french'); in this what is content here?

Comment: @Athi I edited the answer. In your controller you need to load the language keys and pass the the view. See edited answer.